# angularjs: test service call inside scope.$on

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I have a directive as below:

```
app.directive('Directive', ['MyService', '$state',
    function (MyService, $state) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'partials/sample.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                scope.$on('onEvent', function (event, result) {
                    MyService.getInfo($state.params.param1, result.data.value1, result.data.value2)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            scope.varX = response.data;
                        });
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

The test case written for this directive is as below:

```
it('MyDirective test case', function () {
    mockBackend.whenGET('partials/sample.html').respond('<div>Test Template</div>');
    var scope = rootScope.$new(),
        element,
        expectedResult = [
            {
                "data": "dummy"
            }];

    element = compile('<MyDirective></MyDirective>')(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    expect(scope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('onEvent', [{value1: 'val1', val2: 'val2'}]);
    mockBackend.flush();

    var testScope = element.isolateScope();
    expect(testScope.varX).toEqual(expectedResult);
});
```

On running the test case, I get the below error:

```
Directive: appDirectives MyDirective test case FAILED
Expected undefined to equal [ { data : 'dummy' } ].
```

The `testScope` is not getting the `var` variable assigned.
What am I doing wrong in the test case?

Comment: You can take a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/dc1bymzm/. In your test you dont need to test `scope.$broadcast` called because on your directives there is no part of your code doing `scope.$broadcast`. And you have to call `$rootScope.$broadcast` to trigger `$scope.$on` in your directive. About the `$templateCache`, I am not sure why in this code you can not use `$httpBackend.whenGet` (you can try to replace it with `$templateCache` to see the difference).

Comment: Thank you.. You could have marked it as an answer. :D